# Android 4.3 flickering textlines in Textview (within scrollview)

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I've got this weird problem with Android 4.3 textlines disappearing from the textview when text is longer than and scrolling higher than 'match_parent height'. Anyone noticed this and found a solution to it? The bottom line visible will show, but when scrolling up a bit it disappears.

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/nowback"
android:id="@+id/view1"
tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_tekst"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alpha="0.9"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with "alpha" component in textview. I'm having same issue but within ViewContainer's that contains textview and they all flicker if I set alpha less than 1.0

Answer (score 0):

When no of line will increase in text view then it will start flicker. so please either fix  no of line in text view or remove no of line at a certain time.